# what is the official site of diamond bicycle or frame(not "diamondback")

Tags: road-bike, frames, shimano, city

im go to shop and buy a bike that its name **diamond** not **diamond back**
has **shimano** gears and vbreak and has **kenda** tires and frame is steel
do any one know this bike is **made in where**?
and what is official **website** for this bike?
thanks a lot

Comment: From the description its most likely a BSO and probably assembled in a random factory in a 3rd world country. Location of sale would be needed, but even then its most likely to be nothing more than a sticker giving the bike the name. I would be stunned if such a bike had an official website.

Comment: Consider asking the shop directly.  They sell the things, so they must get them from an importer/distributor somewhere.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like it's a Belgian manifacturer: http://www.cyclesdiamond.be/